# ParseTwitterUtils initialize throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, twitter, parse-platform

I am getting a NullPointerException from calling

```
ParseTwitterUtils.initialize(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
```

Here is the stack trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.myapp.app.android.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File com.parse.ParsePlugins.getParseDir()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5015)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5837)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File com.parse.ParsePlugins.getParseDir()' on a null object reference
            at com.parse.Parse.getParseDir(Parse.java:313)
            at com.parse.ParseCorePlugins.getCurrentUserController(ParseCorePlugins.java:124)
            at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUserController(ParseUser.java:56)
            at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUser(ParseUser.java:892)
            at com.parse.ParseUser.getCurrentUser(ParseUser.java:879)
            at com.parse.ParseUser.registerAuthenticationProvider(ParseUser.java:1125)
            at com.parse.ParseTwitterUtils.getAuthenticationProvider(ParseTwitterUtils.java:20)
            at com.parse.ParseTwitterUtils.initialize(ParseTwitterUtils.java:50)
            at com.myapp.app.android.Application.onCreate(Application.java:42)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5012)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5837)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

My app used to work before I added the line `ParseTwitterUtils.initialize(...)`. Here is the onCreate method of my Application class

```
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    registerDatabaseTables();
    ParseTwitterUtils.initialize(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
}
```

Comment: can you paste your custom application class code and android manifest.xml

Comment: @virendrao I have added the onCreate method. Note that the code used to work fine before I added the ParseTwitterUtils call. I figure if I were missing a library jar it should not have compiled at all. Anyway, I am following the instructions on `parse.com`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the instructions on parse.com do not say this, but you have to initialize Parse before you initialize Twitter. This is not obvious since you are required to do so much before you initialize parse. So anyway change your code to this:

```
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    registerDatabaseTables();
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
    ParseTwitterUtils.initialize(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
}
```

Comment: can you help with this parse.com/cloudinary question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866748/sign-cloudinary-upload-request-method-not-found-in-parse-cloud