# sign_cloudinary_upload_request method not found in parse cloud

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, cloudinary

I am using cloudinary with Parse. When I try to upload a video I am getting the below error from my Parse cloud. The error seems to be saying that the method `cloudinary.sign_cloudinary_upload_request(…)` does not exist. Any ideas how I might fix this?

Here is the error:

```
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'sign_cloudinary_upload_request'
at main.js:64:33
at com.parse.ParseRequest.newPermanentException(ParseRequest.java:348)
at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTCommand.java:271)
at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:196)
at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:192)
at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:610)
at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:702)
at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:690)
at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here is the `main.js` portion in question, line 64 is `cloudinary.sign_cloudinary_upload_request(…)`

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sign_cloudinary_upload_request",function(request,response){
    if(!request.user || !request.user.authenticated()){
        response.error("Needs an authenticated user");
        return;
    }
    response.success(
                     cloudinary.sign_cloudinary_upload_request({tags:request.user.getUsername(),eager:{crop:"fill",width:THUMBNAIL_WIDTH,height:THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT,gravity:"face"}})
    );
});
```

Comment: I thought the cloudinary tag was supposed to catch the attention of cloudinary dev relations. Nothing at all? I am blocked by this.

Comment: And how about the parse dev relations guys, what might cause this?

Comment: did you migrate your app to parse-server yet? if yes, are you able to use same cloudinary_parse module with parse server without any errors?

Answer (score 1):

If you had just copied and pasted the code it would work. Your "problem" is that you seem to be typing everything in yourself. So no, there indeed is no such method as `cloudinary.sign_cloudinary_upload_request` the method is `cloudinary.sign_upload_request` refer to the sample: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_parse/blob/master/sample/cloud/main.js

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sign_cloudinary_upload_request", function(request, response) {
    if (!request.user || !request.user.authenticated()) {
        response.error("Needs an authenticated user");
        return;
    }
    response.success(
        cloudinary.sign_upload_request({tags: request.user.getUsername(), eager: {crop: "fill", width: 150, height: 100, gravity: "face"}})
    );
});
```

Just copy and paste: keep it simple.